# Prepared statements error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement, fetch

During debug process, I noticed that script dies on `$stmt->fetch() or die($stmt->error);` line. There is no error in PHP log. Also it doesn't echo any error. Do you see any wrong piece in code?

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT e.msg_subject AS subject, e.msg_text AS text, u.fname AS firstname, u.lname AS lastname FROM emails AS e, users AS u WHERE e.msg_status=? AND e.msg_type=? AND u.id=?") or die($db->error);
    $stmt->bind_param("isi", $status, $type, $userid) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->execute() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->bind_result($subject, $text, $firstname, $lastname) or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->fetch() or die($stmt->error);
    $stmt->close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `$stmt->fetch()` returns boolean `FALSE` if no rows are retrieved by the SQL statement. So, you have to check for the number of rows:

```
if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
    $stmt->fetch() or die($stmt->error);
}
```

Comment: Nope. I don't think. It will return all the given user's messages, having the given status and type.

Comment: Now the error on line `if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {` Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::rowCount()

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I've written it PDO-style. Use the ```num_rows``` property: ```$stmt->num_rows```.